# Create synonym in SQL server 2014 pointing to specific instance

Tags: sql-server, synonym

I have 2 databases servers

Server 1: `Server1/Sql2014` (Sql2014 is the name of the instance)

Server 2: `Server2/Sql2014`

Can I create a synonym from server 2 to server 1 for table MyTable?

From the server 2 I tried:

```
CREATE SYNONYM MyTable FOR [Server1/Sql2014].[MyDatabase].[MyTable]
```

It does not work

Comment: Did you create linked server for `Server1/Sql2014`?

Comment: Thank you! I am new using SqlServer. This is what was missing

Comment: Also, you need to use 4-part names when referring to a linked server object.  For example, [Server1/Sql2014].[MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable].

Comment: @AlejandroMosquera, you are welcome )